# perl split file based on file string

Tags: perl

I am trying to split a very large file into smaller files based string within the file.

eg. Input file

```
 Block(A){
   Block_area : 2.6112;
   Block_footprint : 3BAA5927A22E66B0AE1214A806440F12;
 }
 Block(B){
   Block_area : 2.6112;
   Block_footprint : 3BAA5927A22E66B0AE1214A806440F12;
 }
 Block(C){
   Block_area : 2.6112;
   Block_footprint : 3BAA5927A22E66B0AE1214A806440F12;
 }
```

I want to create three files each containing the data within the brakets

Could you please let me know where I am getting it wrong. my perl code

```
while (<PR>) {
    if ($_ =~ ' Block\('))
    {
        chomp;
    close (PW);
        $textcell = $_;
        $textcell =~ s/Block\(//g;
        $textcell =~ s/\)\{//g;
    open (PW, ">$textcell.txt") or die "check file";
    }
    if ( /^  Block\($textcell\)/../^  }/)
    { print PW  $_;}
}
```

The desired files are being created but are empty.

regards

---

Desired output, three files:

A.txt

```
 Block(A){
   Block_area : 2.6112;
   Block_footprint : 3BAA5927A22E66B0AE1214A806440F12;
 }
```

B.txt

```
 Block(B){
   Block_area : 2.6112;
   Block_footprint : 3BAA5927A22E66B0AE1214A806440F12;
 }
```

C.txt

```
 Block(C){
   Block_area : 2.6112;
   Block_footprint : 3BAA5927A22E66B0AE1214A806440F12;
 }
```

Comment: Please add a sample of your desired output, too.

Comment: How many spaces are there before the `Block(`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your tests exclude anything that isn't a `Block()` line. You do nothing at all for any other forms of the line. In addition, your second `if` statement is checking that there are *two* spaces before `Block`, which never occurs.

This is how I would write it. It assumes at least version 10 of Perl 5 so that I can use `autodie` instead of checking the success of each `open` call explicitly. Note that I have used the `/x` modifier on my regular expression, so spaces and tabs are insignificant and I can use them to make the regex more readable.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

open my $in_fh, '<', 'blocks.txt';

my $out_fh;

while (<$in_fh>) {
  open $out_fh, '>', "$1.txt" if / Block \( (\w+) \) /x;
  print $out_fh $_ if $out_fh;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing approach and read file in blocks instead of lines,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

# input record separator is now '}' followed by old value of separator (i.e \n)
local $/ = "}$/";

while (<>) {
  my ($file) = m|\( (.+?) \)|x or next;

  open my $fh, ">", "$file.txt";
  print $fh $_;
  close $fh;
}
```

Comment: I find it useful to `use 5.010` before `use autodie`. That way Perl complains that it is an insufficient version, rather than a less-helpful message about not finding `autodie`.